# TRPC No query-procedure on path r.getAll but exists | Edit: Is ignoring first 3 characters of query

Tags: next.js, apache2, trpc

I have a next application on t3 stack + next ui, my problem is when I try to deploy this to apache2 webserver, I manage to see the aplication on the browser in a subdirectory, log in the appplication, seed the database, etc. but theres a weird problem on the request from trpc api, let me explain:

When my application tries to retrieve data from the current user and all the users this happens:

The endpoint is consulted like this: `http://example.com/application/api/trpc/user.getAll,user.getCurrentUser?batch...`

And you can see is trying to retrieve both in the same endpoint, user.getAll and user.getCurrentUser, the problem is user.getAll retrieves:

```
{
   "error":{
      "json":{
         "message":"No \"query\"-procedure on path \"r.getAll\"",
         "code":-32004,
         "data":{
            "code":"NOT_FOUND",
            "httpStatus":404,
            "path":"r.getAll",
            "zodError":null
         }
      }
   }
}
```

but user.getCurrentUser retrieves:

```
{
   "result":{
      "data":{
         "json":{
            "id":"user1",
            "name":"Alice",
            "Nomina":"123456",
            "email":"a@tec.com",
            "emailVerified":null,
            "Estatus":true,
            "id_Nivel":"nivel1",
            "image":null,
            "hashedPassword":"$2a$10$qEd9YKrtImuSwEcI990pke6tHwH3gj3ZQJNxrB9Jo1AksK50W0iBm"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Sounds like user.getAll is not defined, right?

Well if the request is made like: `http://example.com/application/api/trpc/user.getCurrentUser,user.getAll?batch...` now is the getCurrentUser query the one that doesn't retrieve data and the user.getAll retrieves data as it should be.

Even if you made a request like: `http://example.com/application/api/trpc/user.getAll,user.getAll,user.getCurrentUser?batch...`
The first getAll will fail, then the second getAll will retrieve something and as well the getCurrentUser, so, just the first one fails.

The query alone also retrieves same error: `http://example.com/application/api/trpc/user.getAll?batch...`

TRPC log just retrieves me the same error `tRPC failed on r.getAll: No "query"-procedure on path "r.getAll"` on the console

My apache2 config is like this:

```
    <Location "/application">
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3001/application
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3001/application
    </Location>
```

edit: dependencies look like this:

```
    "@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "1.0.7",
    "@nextui-org/react": "2.2.9",
    "@prisma/client": "5.7.0",
    "@t3-oss/env-nextjs": "0.7.1",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "4.36.1",
    "@trpc/client": "10.44.1",
    "@trpc/next": "10.44.1",
    "@trpc/react-query": "10.44.1",
    "@trpc/server": "10.44.1",
    "bcryptjs": "2.4.3",
    "framer-motion": "10.16.16",
    "next": "14.0.4",
    "next-auth": "4.24.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "superjson": "2.2.1",
    "zod": "3.22.4"
```

I cannot figure it out if its maybe something dealing with the reverse proxy, but its so weird just the first one fails, so maybe is something asyncronous in the first query?

At this point I don't know what to try, I check the procedures, check the proxy, but I don't know what it could be. I don't know if could be related to the fact that the webserver is just slow, is a toy server to try things then pass it to the real environment. But besides that I dont know where to check

Edit: I have figure it out that it cuts the first 3 characters of the query, example: `http://example.com/application/api/trpc/123user.getAll?batch=1&input=%7B%220%22%3A%7B%22json%22%3A%7B%22limit%22%3A5%2C%22page%22%3A1%2C%22searchName%22%3A%22%22%2C%22orderBy%22%3A%22name%22%2C%22orderDirection%22%3A%22asc%22%7D%7D%7D` would be fine, where `http://example.com/application/api/trpc/user.getAll?batch=1&input=%7B%220%22%3A%7B%22json%22%3A%7B%22limit%22%3A5%2C%22page%22%3A1%2C%22searchName%22%3A%22%22%2C%22orderBy%22%3A%22name%22%2C%22orderDirection%22%3A%22asc%22%7D%7D%7D` not, but I dont know why